# Angular js : ng-click-active not triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this div with ng-click event. The function works perfectly. But the ng-click-active class is not added to the div. 
How is that possible?
Thanks.

Comment: Which `div` do you have?

Comment: <div class="button absolute" ng-click="getCurrentLocation()">Get Location</div>
the getCurrentLocation function works though

Comment: The `ng-click-active` class is added if you're using `ngTouch`, it's not part of the standard `ngClick` directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-click-active` will only appear when the `ngTouch` module is being used. For more information on `ngTouch`, refer to the docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch